# Finding a place for shower after arrival at Los Angeles airport

Tags: usa, lax

I want to take shower near by LAX after arrival by an international flight.

While googling, I found following options:

- Half-day stay at near by inexpensive hotels (Travelodge provide such a service), which costs around $80
- Use near by gyms

Are there any good option other than these?

As I remember correctly, there was a shower place somewhere in the terminal in past, which doesn't exist anymore (Verified at LAX's web site).

Answer (score 2):

Are you transiting to another flight?  Do you have frequent flyer status with any of the alliances?  Some of the airline lounges have showers (Delta, United, etc) and some offer day passes that you might be able to purchase.  They are in the secure areas, so you would likely need to show an appropriate boarding pass to enter that part of the terminal.

Comment: Thanks. I'm arriving LA this time. But I use LAX for transit time to time so I want to find a solution. I'm currently don't have any elite at United but I was United 1K/1P and is OneWorld gold for long time. As far as I know, United at LA does not provide shower services. I don't know about Delta's service (and currently don't have plan to get Delta's elite status), but I couldn't get info on services available for any elite members. Services like 'arrivals by united' provided at near-by Hotel as I remember.

Comment: Delta Sky Club does have showers, as I transit trough there from time to time and that is my lifesaver after umpteen hours of flying from Asia.  Someone said United also did, but I haven't flown United through LAX in a number of years so can't be certain.  But if you are finishing your trip there, heading for a hotel might be the best option.